# Отмерить 30 секунд от даты

Tags: laravel

В базе данных указана дата `end_at`, как написать условие

```
if (если до end_at остается 30 секунд) { 
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$end = new Carbon($end_at);
$now = Carbon::now();
if ($end->diffInSeconds($now) <= 30) {
    // ...
}
```